# Слияние двух записей одной таблицы (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Для простоты упростим реальную таблицу до двух полей, id и summa

```
----+----------
id  !   summa
----+----------
1   ! 5
----+----------
3   ! 7 
----+----------
4   ! 9
----+----------
5   ! 3
----+----------
6   ! 7
----+----------
```

Необходимо слить две определенные записи в одну, например с id = 5 добавить сумму
к id = 3, затем запись с id = 5 удалить.
Что-то типа

```
UPDATE table   
SET summa = (SELECT SUM(summa) FROM table WHERE id = 3 or id = 5) WHERE id = 3; 
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 5;
```

Алиасы не помогают, подходящего примера не нашел.

Comment: `update table A join table B on B.id=5 set A.summa=A.summa+B.summa where A.id=3`

Answer (score 0):

Как и указал Mike.
Разве что следует еще позаботиться об целостности данных.
Мало ли что случится. В запрос попадет ошибочный ID записи, например.

```
mysql_query
("
Update tbl as a, tbl as b
set a.sum = a.sum + b.sum, b.sum = 0, b.remove_flag = 1
where a.id=3 and b.id=5;
Delete from tbl where remove_flag and ID=5
");
```

Так запись с ID=5 будет удалена только в том случае, если её значение было успешно прибавлено к записи ID=3